# duration of candy use during 1 year pre and 1 year post reference period

Tags: sql, netezza

Assuming a student eats only 1 candy per day. I need to find out how many candies a student consumed before the start of school(as shown in the column "Total_candies_consumed_one_year_before_start_of_school") and within 1 year from start of school(as shown in the column "Total_candies_consumed_one_year_after_start_of_school") in red font. My data is as shown in the table with black font. I calculated the highlighted columns. I have provided rationale on how to calculate the "Total_candies_consumed_one_year_before_start_of_school" and rationale to calculate the "Total_candies_consumed_one_year_after_start_of_school".

[image: data and rationale]

The tricky part is how to exclude counts that happened before "school start date" and after end of one year look forward period.

@GMB solved how to calculate for pre-period as

```
select
    t.*,
    number_of_candies *
        greatest(
            least(school_start_date, consumed_date) 
            - greatest(purchase_date, add_months(school_start_date, -12)), 
            0
        ) / (consumed_date - purchase_date) candies_consumed_during_loopback
from mytable t].
```

Is there a way to modify above code for 1 year post period. I have tried replacing the '-12' with 12, didn't work. I have flipped least-greatest inside the greatest parenthesis-didn't work.

If any one could show me how to modify above code to calculate for 1 year post period that would be awesome!

Comment: Thanks to Jack Douglas for providing a much cleaner approach to the entire solution: select mytable.*
     , greatest(0,
         least(consumed_date,school_start_date)-
         greatest(purchase_date,school_start_date-365)) consumed_in_prev_year
     , greatest(0,
         least(consumed_date,school_start_date+365)-
         greatest(purchase_date,school_start_date)) consumed_in_school_year
from mytable;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jack Douglas for providing a much cleaner approach to the entire solution:

```
select mytable.*
     , greatest(0,
         least(consumed_date,school_start_date)-
         greatest(purchase_date,school_start_date-365)) consumed_in_prev_year
     , greatest(0,
         least(consumed_date,school_start_date+365)-
         greatest(purchase_date,school_start_date)) consumed_in_school_year
from mytable;
```